# Array List Variables Using LibGDX

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

i'm working on a game in LibGDX and im stuck with array lists. My plan is to have a deck of 20 cards. Each position in the array list will have its own card which will contain values for stats.

Below is my card class:

```js
public class Card {   
    private String name;
    private int force;
    private int attack;
    private int defense;
    private int cost;
    public Card(String name, int force, int attack, int defense, int cost){
        this.name = name;
        this.attack = attack;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.defense = defense;
        this.force = force;
    }    
    public int force (){
        return this.force;      
    }   
    public int attack (){
        return this.attack;      
    }  
    public int defense (){
        return this.defense; 
    }   
    public int cost (){
        return this.cost;
    }    
    public String name(){
        return this.name;
    }  
}
```

This is my deck class which is where I need help with the code for implementing the values for the cards.

```js
public class Deck {  
    private Array<Card> cards;
    private String name;
    private int force;
    private int attack;
    private int defense;
    private int cost;  
    public Deck(){
        cards.size = 20;
    }
    
    public void createDeck(){
        
    }
    public void shuffle(){
        
    }   
    public void draw(){
        
    }   
    public void add(){       
    }   
}
```

In short, I need help running through the array list and placing the attack, defense, cost, and force to each array position. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initialize the size of an `Array` like this:

```
public Deck(){
    cards.size = 20;
}
```

`Array` is an interface so you need an instance of `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList` is a dynamic array object, so you don't need to provide the size of the Array.

You only need to `add` the elements to the Array.

Or you can use an primitive array, but you should be careful because this type of array cannot change its size dynamically.

The **first** option can be like this:

```
private Array<Card> cards;

...

public void createDeck(){

   cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

   cards.add(new Card("Name1", 1, 2, 3, 4));
   cards.add(new Card("Name2", 5, 6, 7, 8));
   cards.add(new Card("Name3", 9, 10, 11, 12));

}
```

The second option with primitive arrays:

```
private Card cards[];

...

public void createDeck(){

   cards = new Card[20];

   cards[0] = new Card("Name1", 1, 2, 3, 4);
   cards[1] = new Card("Name2", 5, 6, 7, 8);
   ...
   cards[19] = new Card("Name20", 50, 60, 70, 80);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a String array like so

```
int ammountOfMethods = 7; //Arbitrary number, but whatever you'd need
String[]  stringArray = new String[ammountOfMethods];
stringArray[0] = "force";
//Etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Java 8, I recommend the streams API for this.
e.g.,

```
public void createDeck(Array<Card> cards, String name){
    this.cards = cards;
    this.name = name;
    this.force = cards.stream()//a stream is a functional, glorified forEach with a nice API 
        .mapToInt(Card::force) //changes the stream into ints (the card's force value)
        .sum();                //gets the total.
    . . .
}
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html for more information.

If you need additional guidance, leave a comment and I'll expound.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why the deck has the same stat values (name, force, attack, defense, cost) as the cards? Because it seems like the deck should only hold the cards and then each card would have its own set of stats and the stats would be different for each card.

In regards to creating the cards and giving them their initial values, somehow you have to specify the stats for each card. You can either hard code these values or if you want the cards' stats to be different each time you play you could use random number generation to select values with specified ranges. Then you will need to instantiate (create) cards from these values and add them to your deck.

The createDeck() method is where you'd want to create the deck, create the cards, and them to your deck.

Here is an example of hard coding the stat values for cards "Knight", "Troll", and "Wizard" and adding them to the deck:

```
public void createDeck(){
   cards = new Array<Card>(Card.class);

   cards.add(new Card("Knight", 50, 25, 35, 200));
   cards.add(new Card("Troll", 25, 27, 29, 350));
   cards.add(new Card("Wizard", 78, 96, 60, 500));
   ...
}
```

Do this 20 times and it will fill your deck with 20 unique cards.